# Solving equation $\phi ''(x) − 3\phi '(x) + x\phi(x) = \ln x$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help me how to approach this problem in solving please. It is second order differential equation.

$$\phi ''(x) − 3\phi '(x) + x\phi(x) = \ln x$$

It is an Initial Value Problem with $\phi(0)=1$ and $\phi'(0)=0$.
Any kind of help is helpful for me.

Comment: The qualification "[a]ny kind of help is helpful for me" is not useful to your Readers in formulating a response.  It would improve your Question to explain what you do understand about such problems, as an Answer can then pick up where your lessons have left off.  As currently phrased the post will likely appear to be an appeal for someone to do your thinking for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $\phi(x) = e^{\alpha x} \psi(x)$ for a particular choice of $\alpha$, you can transform the above equation to the [Airy equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function), which has two known solutions. Then, you can solve the inhomogeneous equation by the method of [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#General_second_order_equation).